# Adding "active" color for custom Kendo UI grid button

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, pseudo-class

I'm trying to add a colorful custom button to a Kendo UI grid.

It works great except for the active state. Background color doesnt get overrided.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-details" href="#">
    <span class=" "></span>
 Details</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.k-grid-details {
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    border-color: #003399;
    background-color: #003399;
    background: linear-gradient(#003399, #000167);
}

    .k-grid-details:hover {
        border-color: #003399;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #003399;
    }

    .k-grid-details .k-state-active,
    .k-grid-details:active {
        background-color: #003399;
    }
```

What might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/d68h4q2c/2/)

your problem is that you are using `background` + `background-color` in your `.k-grid-details`
but when you hover and active the `.k-grid-details` just do the `background-color`, therefore the `background` (which contains `linear-gradient(#003399, #000167)`)stays on hover and active state. so you must join background-color and background, making it shorthand, like this:

**`background: #039 linear-gradient(#003399, #000167)`**

you can see more for **background shorthand** [**HERE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

then in your hover and active state just after the background color, you set none for the linear-gradient, like this:

```
.k-grid-details:hover {
        background: #ff0 none;
}

.k-grid-details:active {
        background: #f00 none;
}
```